# How to create a push id for firebase using golang?

Tags: firebase, go, firebase-realtime-database

i want to push a map to firebase with an id (eg:-KfKoScgRhylaLjQlK-y)

```
fitToWorkMap := make(map[string]models.TaskFitToWork)
    fitToWorkForTask :=models.TaskFitToWork{}
    for i := 0; i < len(FitToWorkSlice); i++ {
        fitToWorkForTask.Info =FitToWorkSlice[i]
        fitToWorkForTask.DateOfCreation =time.Now().Unix()
        fitToWorkForTask.Status = helpers.StatusPending

        fitToWorkMap["fgsgdsfn+'i'"] = fitToWorkForTask
    }
    task.FitToWork = fitToWorkMap
```

here fitToWorkMap is a map .i want to generate a key for this map

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those keys starting with `-K` are called push IDs and they are automatically generated by Firebase:

- When you [call `push()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#append_to_a_list_of_data) or `childByAutoId` in one of the supported SDKs
- When you perform a [`POST` request to the REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/save-data#section-post)

There is no Firebase SDK for Go and uses the REST API to interact with the Firebase Database. That means that it only generates a push ID when it `POST`s a new node to the database. I don't know of any library for Go to generate Firebase push IDs client-side.

But luckily the [keys are quite well documented in a blog post](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/02/the-2120-ways-to-ensure-unique_68.html). The [code for a JavaScript implementation of `generatePushID()`](https://gist.github.com/mikelehen/3596a30bd69384624c11) is also available, so you could port that over to Go.